# Does a PHP script executed with exec() from a web-accessible endpoint have access to $_POST?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a web service endpoint that needs to invoke another developer's CLI PHP script as part of its run.  Pseudocode like so:

```
function startCLI($input, $output){

  $cmd = escapeshellarg('php bin/startcli.php $input $output');
  exec($cmd, $output, $ret);

  if ($output){
    print_r($output[0]);
  }
}
```

Now, you might be asking: why not pass the `$_POST['var']` to the `clistart.php` script?

Well, you get what you pay for when you get your legacy code from overseas, sometimes, and the time it would take me to take apart their system and put it back together is greater than the time I have to implement the whole solution.

So let's just stipulate that I cannot add new variables to the `clistart.php` script, and take it from there.  Hell, take it as an academic exercise.  Does a CLI script executed from a web-requested PHP script have access to $_GET or $_POST for its run?

UPDATE: I've tried both adding keys to $_ENV and `getenv()` and `putenv()`, but the result is the same - I can update the environment for the current script and the child script that it's executing to QUEUE the job, but since the jobs are then being run by a persistent process that has its own $_ENV context, there doesn't appear to be a way to pass that variable along to the persistent process' context.

I'll either have to resort to the database or a file touch, unless someone has another idea.

Comment: It would be trivial to test this (`print_r($GLOBALS)`), and would certainly consume less time than it took you to write the question and wait for the answer.

Comment: I'm still missing something; can you give examples of the different ways you'd use `clistart.php` from the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

$_GET and $_POST are part of the scripts web request context and won't be available in CLI, it will have it's own context populated.

Comment: It depends on the type of php binary used. If you run the second script over the PHP-CGI variant, then `$_GET` will be populated since `QUERY_STRING` is in the environment. Transferring $_POST would also be possible, but needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

Not without exporting the array contents as environment variables - via putenv.

But why is a CLI script looking into HTTP variables anyway? A CLI-only script wouldn't even look at them.

Or by CLI do you mean it's designed to run as a CGI script?

Comment: The CLI is a generic 'job-flow' application - it makes sure that the server's resources aren't taxed (running ffmpeg, among other things, though this persistent service).  It's just concerned with the load on the server, and wasn't written with the web in mind originally. I'm adding a web component to it.  Getting access to 1-2 variables in the $_POST is the alternative to shutting the service down and bringing it back up with a new configuration.

Comment: I'm missing something here, what variables is the CLI script looking for that you can't pass as arguments in exec() or environment variables via putenv?

Comment: This persistent job-management code is old, fragile and out of my scope.  Modifying it to receive a new variable on creating the queued jobs isn't worth the likelihood that it will break.  I prefer to black-box it and work around the internals until fixing it is in scope.  :)